# Выполнение SQL запроса по расписанию

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование

В таблице имеются 2 поля login и token. Как сделать так, чтобы после того как в поле token для указанного логина будет записана информация, это поле очиститься через сутки?

Использую MySQL

Comment: Создать одноразовый эвент на обнуление нужного поля нужной записи. Не помню, возможно ли это из триггера, если нет - то в триггере просто слить все данные в служебную таблицу, и регулярным эвентом переварить их в нужный эвент. А если сутки - это плюс-минус вменяемо, то можно и простым чистильщиком обойтись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно вопрос в том, а нужно ли ли тут выполнение запроса по расписанию?

Если немного подумать, то вероятней всего задачу можно переформулировть так:

"Нужно чтобы токен был действующим в течении суток"

Решается она проще и стандартней. В таблицу добавляется поле типа **datetime** или **timestamp**, в которое записывается время в которое был создан токен.

В дальнейшем при проверке токена делается еще и проверка времени его создания. Если токен был создан в течении текущих суток - то токен считается валидным. Если был создан раньше - значит токен нерабочий.